# How to use eventlisteners in functions?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I need to ask confirmation from the user before unloading the page. If I do this in JS, it works:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { //close confirm
    return '';
}
```

but when I place it into a function to make this more flexible, I seems to be not registered:

```
function sth()
{
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', closeConfirm, false);
}

function closeConfirm()
{
    return '';
}
```

Can someone please tell me the difference? Removing is also not working in a function, after event was registered outside the functions in plain JS.
sth() is called by pressing a button. I need to enable this eventlistener on login, and remove on logout or timeout, but I cant make it work with function calls, but just when the page loads.

---REFRESH---
Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6mvuet1h/1/

If you comment out the 2-4 lines, this is not working.

Comment: If you put code in a function, it doesn't run until somehow the function is called.

Comment: Make sure you didn't forget to call the `sth()` function

Comment: Can you provide a complete (minimal) runnable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: when you use addEventListener, you need to remove the `on` prefix. So just use [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#Examples)

Comment: Refreshed, not working :/

Comment: I cannot see where you actually call the `sth()` function in order to bind the event listeren?

Comment: If you read the description, you can see, that I use a button, as implemented in the example. @JeroenBourgois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm editing my answer, because I misunderstood your problem before.

On [beforeundload mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) we can read that some browsers (chrome included) need `event.returnValue` to be set. Some other browsers need `event.preventDefault()` to be called. So your `closeConfirm` function should look like this:

```
function closeConfirm(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = '';
    return '';
}
```

Comment: I need to refresh page when session is over, but page is not reloaded while there is no confirmation from the user. So I need to remove this event listener. After I click the button to register and make some work in the form, I can reload without confirmation, so somehow this registration and remove is not working within functions. Window events may only be working when registered till page load. Any idea?

Comment: It works fine, but you misspelled `removeEventListener` with `rempveEventListener`

Comment: I dont think it is working. You can see here the two versions: http://sth354.mooo.com/ and http://sth354.mooo.com/index2.html I am using Chrome

Comment: @stacki I edited my answer. Always remember to read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. There is a last question: why did the original anonymous function worked when fired at load time? @Konowy